Increment sufficient & providers
Can someone please provide me with an example of when to increase sufficients and providers in an account?
Providers

The providers reference counter prevents Substrate pallets from storing data about an account until the account is active (providers > 0).

Is the account active only when it has an existential deposit?
I noticed the following post but I am still unclear of when to increase sufficients and providers.
What is the meaning of the account provider, sufficients and consumer?

You can find examples of when sufficients and providers are increased or decreased by checking where their corresponding functions are called in the polkadot-sdk codebase.
The functions that manage the increase or decrease of sufficients and providers can be found in the System pallet:

inc_consumers
dec_consumers
inc_providers
dec_providers

Some examples of where these functions are invoked in the polkadot-sdk codebase are the following:

inc_consumers :

assets pallet - new account
session pallet - set_keys
nfts pallet - transfer


dec_consumers:

staking pallet - kill_stash
session pallet - purge_keys


inc_providers:

delegated staking pallet - register_agent



